# How to add a constraint to prevent adding polygons with holes

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have a table in postgres with the following column definition:

```
the_geom geometry NOT NULL
```

I want to constraint it to only simple polygons. I have the following definition to limit it to polygons:

```
ADD CONSTRAINT enforce_geotype_the_geom CHECK ((geometrytype(the_geom) = 'POLYGON'::text)
```

And I want to also limit each polygon to prevent from having holes. Polygons with holes can be create like [here](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.4/ST_MakePolygon.html). I want to prevent that. Is it possible?

Comment: To constraint to polygons only, the simplest is to specify it in the column definition. Use `geometry(polygon)` instead of the more generic `geometry` datatype

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wouldn't this constraint solve the issue?

```
ADD CONSTRAINT enforce_geotype_the_geom 
CHECK ((ST_NumInteriorRings(the_geom) = 0))
```

The ST_NumInteriorRings function returns null if the argument is not a polygon and the number of interiorrings > 0 if there are subrings.

https://postgis.net/docs/ST_NumInteriorRings.html